# Do people/companies using my library need to include my OSS licensing notice?

Tags: licensing, license-notice

I made a library with which I distribute an opensource-licences-readme.txt file disclosing which open-source projects I have leveraged and including their copyright notices and other required info.

I was asked by a company that wants to use my library today if they also need to include this `.txt` file in their product (theirs is a compiled commercial product for sale).  I'm unsure if it's just me that needs to do so, or if they are obliged to copy and redistribute the same license information that I provide, so I haven't been able to advise them.

Comment: Which licence(s) are involved?

Comment: Apache 2.0, MIT, BSD 2-clause, BSD 3-clause

Comment: All three licences are pretty clear about what you're expected to include in a derivative work.  Is there any aspect of any of them that you're unclear about?  Or is your only question whether the commercial project is a derivative of the upstream works as well as yours?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, that.  I have no problem with including the notices myself, but I don't know if the people who use my library should do so.  Whether it just chains endlessly or they can use my work themselves without needing to credit the people I credited.

Comment: @Nande I believe "whether it just chains endlessly" question is answered by the duplicate I've linked. Could you explain what, if anything, needs further clarification?

Comment: Then you should definitely read the answer Philip links to above, which addresses this point, and let us know if it does for you.

Comment: note: if this is your free open source project you have no obligation to answer the company's question. It's their obligation to understand what they are using.